# Where are the non-moderators in Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderators

I've asked [a whole bunch of Meta questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex?tab=questions). It seems that almost all the answers or comments that I've received are from the moderators:

- [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses)
- [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio)
- [Double AA](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)
- [msh210](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/170/msh210)

(For example, [this post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/average-number-of-comments-per-post-mi-yodeya-vs-the-rest-of-the-stack-exchange) has comments from all four moderators but none from anyone else.)

Is it a coincidence that the vast majority of meta discussion is done by the moderators?

Are non-moderators intimidated to express their opinions on how the site should work?

Or do moderators feel additional responsibility to address Meta issues because of their positions?

[Do regular users not know that Meta exists?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/hiding-dangerous-information#comment11005_3691)

Is the quality that pushes someone to become a moderator the same quality that pushes someone to actively participate in Meta?

[Note, I have nothing against the moderators, or the things they say in Meta. I am simply curious as to why it seems that almost no one else seems to be consistently involved. Of course, my impression might simply be wrong.]

Comment: Mods are pung/notified automatically about every new meta post. Other people have to check the site for updates. That's probably why we usually get there first.

Comment: @DoubleAA That might explain it.

Comment: But we're here :-> We see you, we even upvote your posts :-> At the appropriate time we will also comment or answer. But clearly I spend a lot less time on Meta than on the mainsite, and check it much less often.

Comment: @mbloch Good to know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a "real" meta question, than a "super"-meta question or a meta-meta question. You're asking a question about meta on meta. But, in response, I know I have responded / commented to a few questions on meta. And, now, I'm responding to yours. Happy, now?

Comment: @DanF Are you suggesting that we have a Judaism.meta.meta.stackexchange.com for questions like these? :)

Comment: @DonielF You're welcome to suggest this or any other brainy idea.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1282/13438